# Laptop powers down during startup

Tags: hardware-failure, shutdown

When I press the power button, the computer starts just fine, the Windows are loading just fine, then heavy fanning (REALLY loud) is heard for about two seconds and then the computer shuts down. This happens few times in a row, but when the laptop survives the loading, it won't crash in Windows. Also, happens in Ubuntu.

Thinking it's a heat related problem, I cleaned the fan and changed the thermal paste, but the problem persists. I checked the round condensators on the motherboard and they seem fine.

Happens with and without battery or power plugged in. When I measure temperature (openHwMonitor), it's at most 60 during the whole time.

Edit: I cannot get to Windows anymore. I can boot to Ubuntu, but it seems the fan is not turning the whole time. It starts only for the two heavy seconds, but it is silent otherwise the whole time. I also think the fan used to start for a brief moment right after the power button was pressed, but it does not anymore. 
Edit 2: ok it DOES start sometimes in Ubuntu, but it is not running right before it enters the berserker mode.

Comment: 1) Have you checked HDD? Usually maximum allowed temperature for laptop HDDs is 55-60, and they really slow down when reaching it (and get damaged). And some HDDs may force shutdown for not damaging themselves. Also make sure there's no unusual noise coming from HDD 2) Is the temparature 60 after changing thermal paste? Was it 60 before changing? Maybe you haven't changed thermal paste in right way? 3) Try to boot from USB after pulling out HDD (you can try [Ubuntu Live](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)), is it OK?

Comment: It fails the same way even without the HDD and RAM modules.

Answer (score 4):

> ***UPDATE*: I cracked the 2 second problem!**

There may be several factors contributing to this... Some recommended solutions are:

1. Clean your laptop. Few people seem to realize this but dust can actually cause really major problems. Also, try it with a cooling pad beneath it and see any results... Open the case up and use a blower or a compressed air can and blow it all away. [**Rahul's Awesome Tech Tip:** If you don't have a specialized Blower/Air Pump/Compressed Air, try a Hair-dryer on normal mode! (the one without heat)]
2. Take the battery out and disconnect the charger. Then press the power button about 7-10 times. This will drain all extra power out of the motherboard. You'd be surprised at how often this works.
3. Power-Supply Problems/Short-Circuits - Not much you can do about it
4. Try Falcon4BootCD or Hiren's Boot CD, it can be useful.

**Strongly Recommended:** Before trying anything, try to boot into a lightweight OS like DamnSmallLinux, or MiniWindowsXP (preferred) from Falcon4BootCD and take a backup of all your data.

---

**The two second problem:**
I just realized that with most BIOS, At first, when you start a computer, everything is powered for about two seconds-- So, even it I disable the keyboard backlight on my Lenovo y50-70 using the Fn+Spacebar shortcut, the next time I start my computer the backlight lights up for two seconds before the BIOS loads fully and realizes/remembers that it was disabled... The only thing is, since fans are always on, so you never realized this before!

This is NOT a glitch and is normal behavior. This is also why on many computers you'll hear the DVD drive click when they are first switched on.

[What this means: Your BIOS is not corrupt  and you are probably facing a hardware issue like heating]  :P

Answer (score 3):

Do you still have your Windows OS on the drive?   If so, have you tried to revert back to a known, good day say: 2-3 weeks ago?  What about Safe Mode?  I know Safe Mode in Windows 8 is a little funky to get into.  Even though you say that Ubuntu does the same thing may suggest you still have a virii on the drive.

What about going to the OEM: Dell/HP/etc. and looking at:

- Some laptops/desktops have built-in diagnostics within the BIOS for memory/drives/etc.  Results?
- Have you tried to flash/re-flash the BIOS with an updated one?
- Any updated drivers from the OEM?
- What about drivers, e.g. video?

How old is the laptop?  If it is within a year, can you go back on a warranty service/replacement?

Comment: The laptop powers down sometimes even before it gets to the boot menu (grub), usually the first time I try to turn it on, with the heavy fanning, so it is not Windows related. The laptop is about 5 years old. I am going to have a look at the BIOS now.

Comment: I have about 15 seconds in BIOS before the computer powers down and I cannot find any diagnostic tool there.

Comment: What about detaching your hard disk/memory/etc. and see if this allows you in?

Comment: Also dies in the same manner. I tried removing the hdd and RAM modules. I am starting to think this is really an overheating problem, but what could overheat three seconds after cold start?

Comment: If you pulled HDD and Memory, then you probably have something hardware-related wrong..  Like a wire or motherboard trace that is cracked or something?  What led up to this condition?

Comment: It started suddenly after the computer was not plugged in for about a week (otherwise it is plugged in basically the whole year).

Comment: I have no clue..  The only other thing that maybe contributing to this issue is that you had a power spike/surge/sag and your surge protector did not serve it's function..  I am sorry, but I don't have much more to go on.  Divorcing your drive and memory and it still does it.  You tried with Windows and with a LINUX boot.  You could try another Variant of LINUX..  Arch/Puppy or GParted?  But I am still saying it is going to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Had that problem and it was related to processor temp rising too high, so it shuts down itself to avoid physical damage.
Take it to technical service to get it clean inside. Might have dirt between processor and fan, keeping it from cooling properly.

I tried runnung Ubuntu, liveCD and installed (yeah, wiped Win) and it happened to be less intensive, allowing a full boot, discarding physical damage.

Comment: I disassembled and cleaned the computer twice, including changing the thermal paste on GPU and CPU, did not work :/

Comment: It might relate to some shortcirciut or problems in the power supply.

Answer (score 2):

Since the problem arrives in both Windows and Linux, and now even during the POST,
it is most likely a hardware problem.

If the computer is still under warranty, the best solution
is to use that immediately, because too many manipulations may void that
warranty.

If the warranty has elapsed, the possibilities for failing parts are endless,
but in my opinion are principally the PSU and motherboard.
To further isolate the problem, disconnect all possible equipment and take out
all possible cards (if not a laptop) before
booting, to ensure that the problem is not coming from the connected ones.

If you have a spare PSU lying around, try it. Even if the PSU does not fit
inside the case but is of sufficient capacity,
connect the wires just to see if the computer powers up.

If the PSU is not the problem, then I suggest to call upon a qualified
repairman/shop, which might have enough spare parts of all kinds,
with which to identify the faulty one by replacement.

Comment: Yep, it's probably a faulty HW. It's a laptop, so I cannot try most of the ideas you suggested. The thing that puzzles me is the scenario that repeats every time: heavy fanning for two seconds, then power down. Can a faulty MB do that?

Comment: A faulty MB can do anything, but I would check first the PSU. Without knowing too much about your model, this can maybe be checked as described above.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to change a laptop PSU, but I will have a look into that tomorrow.

Comment: For the test, just switch the wires to the other PSU. The PSU will still work even when placed outside of the laptop case.

Comment: @harrymc the PSU of a laptop (which is really just a few regulators) is directly built into the mainboard. Not sure how you'd change that and what wires you're talking about.

Comment: If there are no wires, then my advice does not apply to your laptop model. If this is an all-in-one MB, then probably it needs replacement or a very qualified technician. Verify prices - it might be more economical to buy a new laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crazy problem for sure. I don't believe that 60C is hot enough to make the computer forcefully shutdown to prevent damage, so in my point of view, I don't believe overheating is the issue.

After reading things from other forums, here are a few things you can try.

- Reset/clear the CMOS by removing it for 10 seconds in case something in the BIOS got messed up.
- Replace the CMOS battery. An underpowered or dead CMOS battery can cause a system to fail booting.

The CMOS is the only thing I do not see mentioned in other answers/comments. If replacing the CMOS does not work, I would say the problem is related to the MB. There could be a short circut or some sort of problem that is causing it to not deliver power efficiently. In that case, getting a MB replacement *should* fix your issue.